Infinite orthonormal bases are not Hamel: can we prove this without using Fourier series?
There is a well-known fact that for a Hilbert space $H$ with a choice of an orthonormal basis $\Gamma \subset H$, we have $\dim H < +\infty$ if and only if $\operatorname{span} \Gamma = H$, and consequently, infinite orthonormal bases are not Hamel bases. I think the "canonical" proof is roughly as follows:

If $\dim H < +\infty$ then there is nothing to show.


Conversely, if $\operatorname{span} \Gamma = H$, i.e. if every element $x \in H$ can be written as a finite linear combination of elements coming from $\Gamma$, then the Fourier series $F(x)$ of $x$ with respect to $\Gamma$ must be a finite sum. Suppose now, for the sake of deriving a contradiction, that $\Gamma$ is infinite, and choose a countable sequence $\{e_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset \Gamma$ (which is automatically orthonormal). By the uniqueness of Fourier series, any series of the form $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n e_n$ is the Fourier series of some $x \in H$, hence $a_n \not = 0$ only for finitely many indices $n \geq 1$. However, we also know that in Hilbert spaces, a series of the form $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n e_n$ converges if and only if the series of non-negative real numbers $\sum_{n \geq 1} |a_n|^2$ converges, and there are many such convergent numerical sequences wherein the summands are all non-zero (e.g. $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi}{6}$). Thus, we have a contradiction, so $\Gamma$ must be a finite set, and hence $\dim H = |\Gamma| < +\infty$.

(please let me know if there are any errors!)
Now, my actual question is: is there a way to prove this result without using Fourier series ? Not that Fourier series are "ugly" or anything of the sort, but my gut feeling is that there ought to also be a more "set-theoretic" proof, but I can't think of one on my own.
Thanks in advance!

@geetha290krm it is not uncommon to refer to Fourier series in a general Hilbert space context (obviously drawing on the classical analogy) to mean an expansion in terms of an orthonormal basis but of course the author of any such book must be explicit to emphasize the special case.

I think a shorter proof can be given by considering a countable subfamily ${e_n}$ of your orthonormal basis and the number
$$  x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}e_n$$
which is in the Hilbert space can not be a finite linear combination of elements of your basis. I guess this still counts as using Fourier series though so I'll leave it as a comment.
